# Casting data from TempData , System InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I need to transfer some data from one action to other action , so i decide to use TempData. I tried for test to transfer some List of integer , but casting to list in other action gives a error.
Here is code

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetKorpaItems(List<int> values,List <string> values2, List<int> values3)
    {
        List<int> a = values;

        TempData["key"] = a;

        return Json(new { message = "Success" });
    }

    public ActionResult NarudjbaDetails()
    {
        List<int> ta = (List<int>)TempData["key"];

        return View();
    }
```

And error :
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQhCM.jpg)

Comment: When you debug is values null when you assign it to a? Are you positive the data is being set in the temp data?

Answer (score 0):

Is it between two different requests the data "gets lost"?

TempData have a pretty short life span. If you want to make sure it's kept you can use Keep.

```
TempData.Keep("key"); // Makes sure to keep that particular value
TempData.Keep(); // Keeps all values in TempData
```

Another thing to keep in mind is that if you read something from TempData it's get marked to be deleted. To avoid this you can use Peek instead to "take a look" at the value without marking it for deletion.

```
TempData.Peek("key"); // The value for "key" will not be marked for deletion
TempData["key"]; // The value that is stored with that key will be deleted
```

Hope that makes sense?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1#tempdata

> ASP.NET Core exposes the Razor Pages TempData or Controller TempData. This property stores data until it's read in another request. The Keep(String) and Peek(string) methods can be used to examine the data without deletion at the end of the request. Keep marks all items in the dictionary for retention.

Comment: I dont have problem with lifetime.I found a soultion to cast that tempdata as IEnumerable<int> and that fixed it. Ty for answering anyway .